# QFileDialog localization

Tags: qt

`QFileDialog` is used in my code like following:

```
QFileDialog fileDlg;
fileDlg.setFileMode(QFileDialog::AnyFile);
fileDlg.setViewMode(QFileDialog::List);
fileDlg.setNameFilter("Excel Files(*.csv)");
fileDlg.setDefaultSuffix("csv");
fileDlg.setAcceptMode(QFileDialog::AcceptSave);
fileDlg.exec();
```

Unfortunately, this does not use text from the user's current locale.  I would expect the save button to be "保存".  Further, when I click on a dialog, the button's text is set to "Open", while it should be "打开" in my locale.

How can I provide localized strings to `QFileDialog`?

Comment: What would you expect it to be when selecting a file for saving and a directory is selected? You cannot overwrite a directory with a file.

Comment: yes,but when I clicked a Dir ,the text of Saving button will be changed to system language like "Open" .In my project,language must be   uniform.for example: the language in my project is chinese,the text of saving button is "保存".At the same time,when clicked a Dir ,it should be "打开" not the "Open".

Comment: never use a QObject (and its subclasses) on the stack or disaster will happen. Always use `new`, ie `QFileDialog* fileDlg = new QFileDialog()`.

Comment: UmNyobe:  This isn't true.  It's a modal dialog and will have closed before it goes out of scope.  There's no problem with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this has been answered and accepted but **the correct way is not to manually translate what Qt already provides** but rather to ***load the translations included in Qt*** like this:

```
 /* load the system translations provided by Qt */
 QTranslator qtTranslator;
 qtTranslator.load("qt_" + QLocale::system().name(),
         QLibraryInfo::location(QLibraryInfo::TranslationsPath));
 app.installTranslator(&qtTranslator);

 /* load our custom translations for this application */
 QTranslator myappTranslator;
 myappTranslator.load("myapp_" + QLocale::system().name());
 app.installTranslator(&myappTranslator);
```

This way Qt will translate what it already knows (like it's own widgets) and will use the custom translations provided with the application for the rest.

Comment: But,it doesn't work like following:QApplication a(argc, argv);
 QFileDialog filedialog(NULL,Qt::Dialog);
 QTranslator qtTranslator;
 qtTranslator.load("qt_" + QLocale::system().name(),QLibraryInfo::location(QLibraryInfo::TranslationsPath));
 qDebug()<<"qt_"<<QLocale::system().name();
 a.installTranslator(&qtTranslator);
 filedialog.show();
 return a.exec();

Comment: This is generally good advice. Though I don't see how this should change the "accepted" status of my answer - if the system-translated version of Open is acceptable, then using Qt's translations is preferred. If you want to replace it with a different, custom label, then you'll need to provide your own translation. The generic answer "You'll need to install a QTranslator that translates &Open in the QFileDialog context" is valid for both cases.

Comment: @mac.ma - your sample works for me (e.g. launching with LC_ALL="de_DE" ./qtTest produces a German localized dialog). Are you sure the qt_*.qm files are installed correctly on your system?

Comment: One must make sure that the translators don't go out of scope. In that case the translations are not applied. I made that mistake and wondered a while why there were no correct translations :)

Answer (score 1):

The "Open" string is hardcoded but translated in `QFileDialog`:

```
void QFileDialogPrivate::_q_updateOkButton()
{
// ...
    if (acceptMode == QFileDialog::AcceptSave)
        button->setText(isOpenDirectory ? QFileDialog::tr("&Open") : acceptLabel);
```

You'll need to install a [`QTranslator`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtranslator.html) that translates `&Open` in the `QFileDialog` context to what you want.

Also see [Internationalization in Qt docs](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/internationalization.html) for more info.

Comment: is there other solution for it ? I am a Qter,-_-

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the [static functions](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html#static-public-members) in `QFileDialog`. Those use the native file dialog from the OS, which will be in the correct locale and translation.