# Error from KGlobal::locale while opening a QFileDialog in C++

Tags: c++, linux, qt4, kde-plasma, qfiledialog

I've got this C++ code:

```
bool load ()
{
    const QString * filename = openFileDialog(QFileDialog::AcceptOpen, QFileDialog::ExistingFile);
    if (filename != 0)
        return load(*filename);
    else return false;
}
const QString * openFileDialog (QFileDialog::AcceptMode acceptMode, QFileDialog::FileMode mode)
{
    QFileDialog dialog;
    dialog.setAcceptMode(acceptMode);
    dialog.setFileMode(mode);
    dialog.show();
    QStringList files = dialog.selectedFiles();
    if (files.isEmpty()) return 0;
    return new QString(files.at(1));
}
```

Now, I get the following error:

> KGlobal::locale::Warning your global KLocale is being recreated with a valid main component instead of a fake component, this usually means you tried to call i18n related functions before your main component was created. You should not do that since it most likely will not work

The file dialog never appears.

I'm using Debian wheezy (german), KDE 4.8.4, Qt 4.8.2 and GCC 4.7.2

Comment: Are you aware that you're returning pointer to temporary object?

Comment: @KamilKlimek Yes, you're correct, I replaced that line. But this is not the error; the dialog also never appears after editing that line.

Comment: It seems like some issues with your runtime envoirment - this is not error from Qt

Comment: Also google point out this: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=64&t=93738

Comment: @KamilKlimek I know it's not a Qt error that appears on every machine. I've written my environment at the bottom of the question. Can you show me whats wrong on my code/environment that it doesn't work?

Comment: @KamilKlimek I don't think the asker in your link has the same problem as me. I found this thread already bevore I asked this question, but he invokes a method `i18n` that I don't use, and my code is in a method, so I don't think it helps me.

Comment: Seems like this error is occuring in various conditions - it was never solved - probably you will have to install debugging symbols for libkde and Qt and try debugging it yourself

Comment: @KamilKlimek The application doesn't crash, the `QFileDialog` just never appears. How can I debug something like that?

Comment: add a breakpoint at place where your warning is generated

Comment: @KamilKlimek Thanks, I debugged it and realised that I have to use `dialog.exec()` instead of `dialog.show()`. But the warning still appears and the dialog is still in english. How can I fix this (I have a QTranslator for qt installed as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906944/qfiledialog-localization))?

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, but this is apparently a very old issue anyway.  It was solved 5 years ago, here: http://pyqt.riverbankcomputing.narkive.com/GMKOTskG/a-dire-warning-message#post16

The short answer:

When opening the file dialog, it's using the "system" file dialog.  In this case, the system dialog is KDE, and an issue that is blamed on a KDE library produces that warning.  Want to avoid the issue?  Don't use the "system" file dialog.

In your `openFileDialog` function, simply add:

```
dialog.setOption(QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog)
```

This solution worked for me.  (I'm using PyQt4, but was having the same symptoms.)

Comment: I don't think that the user experience is great if every single application has its own dialog. It makes some sense that there is a system-wide default one if you are using kde. Anyway, this seems to be fixed with Plasma 5, but thanks for sharing your work-around

Comment: For what it's worth, it means that all Qt applications would have a dialog distinct to Qt.  Especially on linux, where you have your choice of window manager, using your UI framework's dialog instead of the window manager's dialog isn't necessarily bad - it's consistent and reliable.  In either case, glad another way around it eventually happened for you.  I added the answer largely because the link with the answer was buried on Google's second page of search results, while your question was 2nd position in the first page.  If others have this problem, they'll find the workaround through here.