# lupdate is not getting tr() strings from QObject objects

Tags: qt, internationalization

I've been trying to make a simple text editor using QT Creator. This text editor has a translatable UI that supports 3 languages: English, Spanish, and Portuguese.

My problem is that every time I run *lupdate*, string literals in my code that are tagged as translatable (i.e. enclosed in tr() ) are parsed and can be edited and translated using QLinguist. However, strings that are part of QObjects (E.g. ButtonText for QFileDialog are not parsed. Am I missing some procedure in order for *lupdate* to parse these strings?

```
void PeterTextEditor::on_actionOpen_triggered()
{
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, tr("Open Document"), QDir::currentPath(),
                                                    tr("Text documents (*.txt)"), 0, QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog);

    if (fileName.isNull())
        return;

    if ( m_fileName.isNull() && !isWindowModified() )
    {
        loadFile(fileName);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        PeterTextEditor * openFile = new PeterTextEditor( fileName );
        openFile->show();
        openFile->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);

    }
}
```

In above example `tr("Open Document")` would be parsed, but QFileDialog has QButton and QLabel objects with strings for button text and label text.These are not parsed. I would like these to be parsed so I could add translations using QLinguist.

Comment: You might find for example the OK button in your dialog and explicitly set its text to "OK" using tr() macro.

Comment: Exactly... I've seen .ts files with the translations for these buttons added. However I do not know how they got lupdate to extract these strings since QFileDialog is a premade QObject.

Comment: Well, maybe these two links might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906944/qfiledialog-localization , http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/11491-Translation-QFileDialog-standart-buttons-%28-quot-Open-quot-quot-Save-quot-quot-Cancel-quot-%29

Comment: okay so this verifies my logic. the implementation of the QFileDialog does have translatable strings. my problem is however to extract these strings from the implementation so I can create a custom translation for them using QLinguist, as the included QT qm files are missing some translations. Perhaps I was being ambiguous.

Comment: If translation files are plain xml file, maybe you can try to add these missing items manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All compiled translation files (*.qm) should be in the `/translations` directory and you would load them as shown in [QFileDialog localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906944/qfiledialog-localization).

Unfortunately, the Qt libraries don't come with all translations for all languages, and, not all the translations supplied are complete.

For the version that I have (Qt 5.2.1), there is a Spanish translation(`qt_es.qm`) of the libraries but there are many strings that have not been translated yet, and there is no translation file for Portuguese(`qt_pt.qm`).

The translation of Qt to other languages is an ongoing project so I suggest you search the web and/or other forums to see if anyone has got updated files you can use.

If you cannot find any, and your Spanish translation is missing a couple of strings you need, you can file the source extraction files(`*.ts`) in the `/Src/qttranslations/translations` directory. Unfortunately, you probably will find only one for Spanish.

If you're willing to start a Portuguese translation, you can extract all the necessary strings you want by running `lupdate` on the `/Src/qtbase/qtbase.pro` file.