# Loading translations for Qt file dialog

Tags: qt, localization, pyqt

I'm trying to internationalise my PyQt program. I have no problem with loading my own translations, but I've noticed things like file dialogs still appear to use the system locale. Answers such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10734791/3419537) suggest that I should be able to translate builtin Qt widgets by installing the translation files shipped with Qt.

I tried loading the German translations that Qt provides, but my file dialog is still shown in English. Will this work with the `QFileDialog` static functions? Am I doing something wrong?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Show dialog')
        button.clicked.connect(self.showdialog)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(button)

    def showdialog(self):
        QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    translator = QtCore.QTranslator()
    if translator.load('qt_de', QtCore.QLibraryInfo.location(QtCore.QLibraryInfo.TranslationsPath)):
        app.installTranslator(translator)
        print 'qt translations installed'

    win = Window()
    win.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Digging deeper into the documentation, I found this:

> **By default, a platform-native file dialog will be used if the platform
>   has one**. In that case, the widgets which would otherwise be used to
>   construct the dialog will not be instantiated, so related accessors
>   such as layout() and itemDelegate() will return null. **You can set the
>   DontUseNativeDialog option to ensure that the widget-based
>   implementation will be used instead of the native dialog**.

So I guess the native dialog is always going to be using the native system language. My example can be made to work by forcing Qt to use the (ugly) non-native dialog

```
def showdialog(self):
    dialog = QtWidgets.QFileDialog(self)
    dialog.setOptions(QtWidgets.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
    dialog.exec_()
```

Comment: But surely for native dialogs, the translation will already be handled by the os, so you don't need to do anything. The only time you'd see a mismatch is if you force your application to use a translator that doesn't match the current locale - and that situation should never arise for the end-user. If you want to test things properly during development, you'll need to change your own system locale, and then make sure your application detects and loads the correct translator.